# NFT marketplace gas fees question

Tags: transactions, gas, nft

I'm working on a nft marketplace as my side project (MERN stack + solidity + web3).

Since each transaction / call to martetplace contract methods will incur a gas fee on the client / user, how should I approach methods like display current auctions or display NFTs owned by a user  ?
Should I store the auctions / nft data in the database and just display them from there in the frontend, or should I get it straight from the chain / contract ? I'm concerned about performance and potential gas cost for those operations

Comment: Reading data from a smart contract doesn't use any gas. You pay gas when you call  a function that modifies the state of the contract.

Comment: So is it enough that I mark it as pure or view in the contract to ensure this is gasles ?